# Is there a way to track down the changes in the filesystem made by a certain app?

Tags: applications

Ok, so I download an app from Google Play and launch it. I'd like to see the behavior of this app, i.e. new directories or files changed/created by this app throughout the filesystem.

Is there, for example, a special app which can track other's apps behavior? Or should I just make a copy of a filesystem before and after running the app, and just compare them? Any other ideas?

---

My device is rooted, runs Android 7.0 (MIUI9 8.2.8).

Comment: Copy of the system before and after is the easiest, Their doesn't seem to be any apps that can recognize the difference in any other way, hypothetically it's not that difficult considering the app just has to check file, folder names and dates along with a md5 checksum of each file to find the difference's